# Guess the distribution from the Moment Generating function

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

If the MGF of a random variable X is 
M<sub>x</sub>(t) = $\frac{1}{3t}(e^t-e^{-2t})$     for $t\neq0$  
Find the distribution of X.

I am currently blank as to how to approach this, a hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Familiarity with common mgf would help.

Suppose $Y\sim [a,b]$,

$$M_Y(t)=E[e^{tY}]=\int_a^b e^{ty} \frac1{b-a}\, dy=\frac{(e^{tb}-e^{ta})}{(b-a)t}$$

Compare with your question and you should be abe to answer the question.

Comment: Oh ok, so remembering certain distribution's MGF helps